# when run the magento2 site I getting this errors in GTmetrix

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, captcha, gtmetrix

When run the magento2 site in GTmetrix I'm getting google recpatcha issues. how to resolve these.
can some one please help me.

[image]

Comment: please share URL

Comment: internally we don't share the urls. it coming under "Optimize the order of styles and scripts" in GTmetrix

Comment: hmm ok so how can I solve it

Comment: maybe you need to check the log.

Comment: can I know where it is generated the log in GTMetrix